# AWS too many requests, Block IP addresses

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

Hi I am running wordpress on my AWS server. And this server is flooded by continues requests from some ip addresses. How can I block them?

```
80.82.78.112 - - [16/Mar/2015:15:29:58 +0000] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0" 200 595 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
```

Each second I am getting around 30-40 request from the same IP address. Which is slowing down my server.

Comment: If its all coming from the same IP, you can use iptables to block requests from the IP address. Unfortunately this is somewhat common, spam bots are trying to use the XML api to post comments directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) to block the offending IPs.
WP is a CMS widely used and is a target for attacks but also Internet is full of resources of people fighting them.

Using fail2ban for blocking xmlrpc requests in Wordpress is documented here: [Countering WordPress XML-RPC Attacks with fail2ban](http://www.scottbrownconsulting.com/2014/09/countering-wordpress-xml-rpc-attacks-with-fail2ban/)

Answer (score 1):

In the hopes this information helps future Googlers, I'd like to extend Diego's recommendation with configuration steps that got me into a working state with fail2ban on an EC2 server.

Environment:

- Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09
- Apache 2.4.27

#### 1. Install and configure the correct version of fail2ban for Amazon Linux

As recommended in [Protecting your Amazon Linux WordPress server using fail2ban](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/aws-amazon-web-services/protecting-amazon-linux-server-fail2ban-cloudflare-wordpress/), install the Amazon-compatible version:

```
yum --disablerepo epel install fail2ban
```

#### 2. Configure **jail.local** and **wordpress.conf**

This configuration is working for both HTTPS and HTTP, and protects against wp-login and xml-rpc attacks.

Create **jail.local**:

```
sudo cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Edit **/etc/fail2ban/jail.local** (add at the bottom):

```
[wordpress]
enabled = true
port = http,https
action = iptables-multiport[name="wordpress", port="http,https", protocol="tcp"]
# Uncomment if you want emails when someone is banned:
#        sendmail-whois[name=fail2ban-wp-bruteforce, dest="your-email@yourdomain.com"]
filter = wordpress
logpath = /var/log/httpd/*access_log
maxretry = 5
```

Create and edit **/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/wordpress.conf**:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> - - .* "POST .*(wp-login.php|xmlrpc.php) HTTP/.*" (200|401|403)
failregex = ^<HOST> - - .* "GET .*(wp-login.php|xmlrpc.php) HTTP/.*" (200|401|403)

ignoreregex =
```

NOTE: I'm using .htaccess rules to return 403 for any `wp-admin/*` resources originating from non-whitelisted IPs (as described in Step 7 of [How to Lock WordPress Admin Login with .htaccess Rules](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/lock-down-wordpress-admin-login-with-htaccess)). If you're not into that, you can safely remove `|403` from the regexes.

#### Related Note: "scoreboard is full" errors may indicate a DDoS attack

Another symptom of DDoS attacks may be a flood of errors in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and/or `var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log` that look like this:

```
[Sun Apr 15 09:10:47.038565 2018] [mpm_worker:error] [pid 2847:tid 140053879679040] AH00288: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers
```

This sent me on a wild goose chase until I correlated the above errors with the `access_log` errors discussed in this question; thought it was worth a mention.